# Firestore GeoQuering in node.js returns null

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, geohashing

I'm trying to create a geoquery in node.js from Firestore, but when using the example from the Firebase library (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries#query_geohashes), my code returns *'Cannot read properties of null (reading 'text')'*.

I want to query for any nearby users in my 'availableDrivers' collection in firebase, based on my current latitude and longitude (hardcoded to a point less than 1km away from the geopoint stored in 'availableDrivers').

Attached is a photo of the database

[image]

What is wrong with my code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { catchErrors } from './helpers';
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const db = admin.firestore();
import * as geofire from 'geofire-common';

export const createFindDriver = async (latitude: number, longitude: number) => {


    // Find cities within 50km of location
    
    const radiusInM = 50 * 1000;

    const bounds = geofire.geohashQueryBounds([latitude, longitude],radiusInM);
    const promises = [];
    for (const b of bounds) {
    const q = db.collection('availableDrivers')
        .orderBy('geohash')
        .startAt(b[0])
        .endAt(b[1]);

        promises.push(q.get());
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
        const matchingDocs = [];

        for (const snap of snapshots) {
            for (const doc of snap.docs) {
                
                const lat = doc.get('driverLat');
                const long = doc.get('driverLong');

                const distanceInKm = geofire.distanceBetween([lat, long], [latitude, longitude]);

                const distanceInM = distanceInKm * 1000;
                if (distanceInM <= radiusInM) {
                    matchingDocs.push(doc.data());
                }

            }
        }

        return matchingDocs;
    })
    .then((matchingDocs) => {
        console.log(matchingDocs);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });

}


export const findDriver = functions.region('europe-west2').https.onCall( async (data, context) => {

    const latitude = data.latitude;
    const longitude = data.longitude;

    return catchErrors(createFindDriver(latitude, longitude));

});
```

Here is my function when it is called:

```
const findDriver = httpsCallable(functions, 'findDriver');

findDriver({ 
  latitude: 51.513958,
  longitude: -0.0858491,
}).then((result) => {
  /** @type {any} */
  const data = result.data;
  const message = data.text;
  console.log(data);
  console.log(message);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log("error.message: " + error.message);
});
```

Comment: ` const message = data.text;`  text is  undefined or null?

Comment: The error thrown was: error.message: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'text')

Comment: From the error message it seems that `data` doesn't have a value in ` const message = data.text;`. You might want to `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` right before that line, to see if `data` is what you expect it to be.

Comment: It, console.log(JSON.stringify(data)), just outputs null

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance it seems that your `createFindDriver` returns an **array** of promises, so you need to handle that array on the result. Assuming that `catchErrors` doesn't do anything with the result, that'd be:

```
findDriver({ 
  latitude: 51.513958,
  longitude: -0.0858491,
}).then((result) => {
  result.forEach((data) => {
    const message = data.text;
    console.log(data);
    console.log(message);
  });
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log("error.message: " + error.message);
});
```